# How not to have your ignorance mistaken for disrespect?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have turned to the Christian faith not so long ago. Thus, I have got very much to learn. Alas, some of my misinterpretations might appear to be too *wrong* to a proper Christian.

I always leave a note before the main body of the post about me being no expert in a field and apologising in advance (in case it is so). I have never been a concise writer (and do not really want to), therefore, this wordy note might not be the best solution.

Which other variants should I consider? I really enjoy this atmosphere of mutual respect on SE and I believe it is weighty to abide by it and keep it intact.

Comment: Long-time Christians sometimes need to be reminded about how to treat recent converts.  Paul specifically dealt with this issue in which people were scaring off new converts with minor details before those converts had come to fully understand the important truths.  E.g. [ethics - Regarding doubt, how do we apply Romans 14 in difficult situations? - Christianity Stack Exchange](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/69004/regarding-doubt-how-do-we-apply-romans-14-in-difficult-situations/69206#69206)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't try too hard.  If someone gives you a hard time in a comment, flag it and we moderators will deal with it.

Because this is a website for learning about Christianity, we expect a civil academic tone in all discourse. Sometimes people will crack jokes in comments, I think this is OK as long as they're not derogatory.

One thing we do require, or at attempt to require, is that *the questions is researched before being asked*.  (i.e. the thing you're asking about should exist, or at least be thought to have existed)

---

Here's a baseline example that I've probably used 1000 times.  Someone asks "Why do Catholics worship Mary?"  That comes up all the time. Now, some say that's fighting words, as if Catholics are idolatrous and some will take offense to it.  But most people respond with just say, no Catholics don't worship Mary, they venerate her, etc...   You can phrase that question in multiple ways that make it look good or bad, but try to give the people you're asking about the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Well put, Peter!

Answer (score 1):

You don't owe anybody any kind of explanation for how much knowledge you have on a religion. You're trying to learn more information and that's great but honestly you don't owe anyone any kind of explanation.